# Which episode of Star Trek: TNG is the image on the chat servers' error pages taken from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, meme

On the three Stack Overflow chat servers, the [chat room not available](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/-1) page displays the following image:

[image: Picard, Riker, Worf rainbow hats]

Is it from an actual episode, or is it a 'shop?

Comment: This looks shopped. I can tell from some of the pixels .... Seriously, that's my hunch, but I don't know the source of the original image so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: A good place to start looking is probably one of the Q episodes.

Comment: The hats are shopped, but I'm pretty sure that image is from a TNG episode.

Comment: I think it's just a cleaned up version of a shopped image. I did a TinEye search. Many of the other versions have different levels or contrast and the fake hat becomes more obvious. Disappointingly, TinEye didn't produce the original screen grab though. http://www.tineye.com/search/f19078846913c90f7d5a2cd10a2758b392d07823/

Comment: Is it me, or is Worf's hat identical to Riker's?  (Check the flaps and how they hang down.)

Comment: Looks like a Jane Hat for all the bridge members...

Comment: Also following the TinEye lead, this might be the source: [http://badassrainbows.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/128/](http://badassrainbows.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/128/) . It's a blog that [adds rainbows to images](http://badassrainbows.wordpress.com/about/), of course.

Comment: What is this?  Dr. Sheldon Cooper meets Star Trek?

Comment: There is software that can detect regions of a jpg editted relative to the rest. I seem to have misplaced a link to an online tool that takes your image and shows you where, maybe someone can post such a site? BTW love this edit.

Comment: https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6926113280/h60423D4C/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Definitely photoshopped.  Worf's sash being silver and not frayed cheap table-cloth-material gold makes it at least 2nd season, but the uniforms make 3rd season or later.

--added for specificity and background--

The simplest way to check this is to go to http://startrek.com and look at stills for ST:TNG episode summaries.

I don't remember all the details, but after the first (or second) season Patrick Stewart threatened to sue Paramount because the one-piece jumpsuits were so tightly fitted they put excessive pressure on their shoulders and spines.  There was an initial change to respond to that issue, then another later change.  While I wasn't able to tell, off the top of my head, when the changes were made, I went to http://startrek.com and checked stills in episode summaries to verify the uniforms.  There's one style in 1st season (the all-in-one), it's changed for 2nd season, and in 3rd season and alter are the simpler collars without the diamond shaped shoulder "pads," just as seen in this image.

Comment: I would suggest that you expand the answer somewhat (e.g. include official cannon references to uniform types/sash colors and/or even screencaps). With that info this could be an exemplary (instead of just good) answer.

Comment: while the image *is* definitely photoshopped, the uniforms *are* all from the same episode, so much of your analysis here doesn't hold up...

Answer (score 108):

I'm re-watching the series at the moment, and I think I have found the scene where that image was originally taken from:

[image: Star Trek: Men with Hats (Sans Hats)]

This is in the teaser for [Deja Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_(episode)) - and the reason they're all looking in different directions is that an annoying high-pitched noise has started on the bridge, so they're all looking for the source. Turns out, this noise is heralding the arrival of a very naked Q.

Original Answer:

The hats are most certainly shopped in - as for the rest of the image, the more I look at it, the more it seems to be a composite. Picard, Riker and Worf are all looking in different directions - which would look a bit silly on TV, although this could just be a momentary thing.

It's also possible that the photo is a promotional image - it has that kind of look to it.

I've tried quite a bit of google image search, and cannot turn up anything that could be the original (the problem is - there are so many shots of these three on the bridge).

Still - judging by the uniforms, I'd say this is probably somewhere in season 3-5 - so if someone is watching these at the moment, they might spot them.

Comment: I'd agree that it's also possible that the characters were edited in as well, but I wasn't sure enough to want to put that in an answer.  That sideways glance Picard has does not look like he's focused on the viewscreen, where everyone else seems focused.  But I don't see enough to state that for certain.

Comment: Nice find!  I'll have to watch for this next time I rewatch that episode.

Comment: Your answer should definitely be the accepted one. That is the original screencap for sure, with Jayne's knit cap obviously shopped onto the characters.

Comment: @Omegacron: Well, Jayne's knit cap wasn't quite as colourful.

Comment: That cursor. Why!? :'(

Answer (score 5):

The hats are likely to be a reference to Firefly -- Jayne's hat from the episode The Message, although the colours aren't quite right.

I couldn't speak for the rest of the image, although even without the hats, the expressions do seem a bit odd, don't they?

Comment: "Man walks down the street in that hat, people know he's not afraid of anything."

Comment: /me launches into a stirring rendition of *The Man They Call Worf*

Answer (score 2):

Photoshopped. To me, it looks like Worf's and Picard's hats are the same, while Riker's is mirrored and then edited a bit.