# What episode of Voyager does this image come from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

I've seen the below image on the internet a few times and was wondering what episode of *Voyager* it comes from, or if it is a genuine image at all!

[image]

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/which-episode-of-star-trek-tng-is-this-image-from

Comment: OH MY LORD. This is incredible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is from the second episode of Voyager (S01E02) '[Parallax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallax_(episode))', where they are approaching a quantum singularity and get trapped inside. It affects the Doctor's holo-projectors and they cause him to shrink. He gets pretty upset about it.

Comment: Well done on a ridiculously fast response time!  You might want to add in the name of the episode as well ;)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing a clip and a link to the episode on Mem:Alpha

Comment: Man alive, the second ever episode?