# Was this the only example of a Starfleet issued hat?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond, star-trek-uniforms

In *Star Trek Beyond*, on Yorktown Station, Starfleet officers are wearing these dress uniform hats.

[image]
[image]

Was this the only example of standard issue **uniform** head apparel?

(Non-uniform, species-specific, and protective/tactical equipment such as helmets don't count.)

Comment: Have to say I hate those hats.  They make Star Fleet look imperialistic.

Comment: @Tim It's a huge nation with a penchant for exploring in heavily armed craft, has a secret police who's charter is classified, and regularly wages war with other galactic powers. It's post-scarcity, but if the shoe fits...

Comment: @Tim: When TWOK came out, a friend of mine complained that the uniforms looked "too Soviet" - I thought they were awesome (and one of the few uniform styles that clearly distinguished officer from crew).  However, I'll agree that these are a bit on the ... shall we say, *hard* side? Like more at home on the Death Star then the Enterprise?

Answer (score 41):

**No.**

The prison guard in *Star Trek III*:

[image]

Also, from TOS, *The Cage* we see a hat, though do not see anyone wearing it:

[image]

Finally (and possibly slightly less canonically), these must be Starfleet issue since the whole bridge crew has the same hat:

[image]

(This is a joke.  This is a well-known photoshopped image.  Discussion of it is on this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/which-episode-of-star-trek-tng-is-the-image-on-the-chat-servers-error-pages-ta).)

Images courtesy of [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/37qg47/starfleet_hats_has_there_ever_been_one_on_screen/).

Comment: Mentioned in the same reddit discussion,  [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0346/5761/products/ste-nx01-hat-2.jpg)

Comment: I would be more inclined to accept this answer if it removed the joke portion, or at least made it very clear it isn't a serious part of the answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I think it's pretty clear it's a joke... you can edit to make it more clear if you like.

Comment: "The last one looks shopped. I can tell from some of the pixels and from seeing quite a few shops in my time."

Comment: @Agent_L To my eyes, the *first* one looks even more shopped!

Comment: This is no joke my friend!

Comment: @Bamboo [Stuff like this makes it hard to be totally certain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3rFNbSKpEE)

Comment: Now I want a Firefly hat to wear with my TNG uniform!

Comment: +1 for the last image alone.  I am sad that's not from a real episode (the addition of the cap makes Stewart's expression *priceless*).

Comment: Before you said it was shopped I was thinking that it could be a little joke from Q

Answer (score 29):

Do headbands count as hats?

Nog was seen wearing a Ferengi-style headband (earband?) in several episodes. Not sure exactly which episodes these screenshots are from, though.

As a cadet:
[image]

As an ensign:
[image]

---

From Memory Alpha, here's a photo of a flag officer from the same era in the Kelvin timeline as in your original question wearing a cap in a different style:

[image]

I also found this example from ST:Enterprise. It's part of the [desert uniform](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Desert_Crossing_(episode)).
[image]

Here's a better image from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(2140s-early_2160s)):
[image]

And a description of when it's worn:

> Available for use with the excursion uniform and standard duty uniform was a black hat, embroidered with the specific registry number of the wearer's home assignment. Made of stretchable material, these hats were essentially one-size-fits-all "baseball caps." While these caps were generally worn during away missions, some officers wore theirs aboard ship.

Comment: No,  because this counts as a species-specific exception.   Ensign Ro also wrote a headband,  which I won't count.

Comment: Was Ro's headband a species-specific exception? I don't recall any other Bajorans wearing anything similar.

Comment: Fair point.  But we never saw it anywhere else,  and she had the earring, so I always assumed it was supposed to be a Bajoran thing, even if that was never carried forward to DS9.

Comment: I want that NX-01 hat.

Comment: It could be argued that the cap qualifies as protective/tactical equipment --  particularly since one is camouflage and the other is paired with the shades.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Wow, you are tough to satisfy. I've added the description from Memory Alpha. The caps were also worn aboard ship, so while it may have originally been for protection, it seems to have crossed over into the realm of fashion/personal choice.

Comment: @miltonaut, well,  need to play devil's advocate to get the best and most complete versions of the answers do I can somehow choose between the two.

Comment: @miltonaut, I should add: is that quote from Memory Alpha?   That is not a primary source.   But if it really was worn on ship  that would indeed bolster the case.

Comment: Malcolm and Trip have NX-01 caps in Shuttlepod One. Memory Alpha is even kind enough to include [a picture](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/a/ab/Trip_and_Reed_in_Shuttlepod_1.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110118171418&path-prefix=en) on both of their character pages.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I didn't include them, but Memory Alpha lists all the episodes in which the cap is seen--both on- and off-ship. I can include them if you'd like.

Comment: You'd probably get more upvotes if you either moved the headband part to the bottom of the post or deleted it altogether, since the OP has indicated that it doesn't match their criteria.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If you are so nitpicking - aren't hats *always* somewhat protective? Even your *Beyond* example protects head and eyes from the sun.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, more than other clothing?   We have the draw the line somewhere.   Basically didn't want specialized equipment involved,  like space helmets because that's not the gist of the question.     The question is really, Is the motivation behind the headgear functional or is it just part of the uniform.   Uniform is the operative concept.

Comment: ... if you are issued sunglasses so you can operate better,  that doesn't make it part of the uniform.   If you are issued a dress uniform hat,  that is primarily for appearance as part of the uniform.

Answer (score 4):

There's also this unfortunate bit of headgear from ST:TMP:

[image]

"Just...give me a red shirt, already.  It's not like I'll be any less dead by the end of the day."

**Edit**

I just noticed the "protective/tactical equipment such as helmets don't count" restriction, and this definitely falls into that category.  But it was also part of the standard issue security duty uniform (if for all of 10 minutes of 1 movie), so I think it *should* count.

Comment: I think that this would fall under "protective/tactical equipment such as helmets don't count".

Answer (score 3):

I feel I should offer this answer for completeness.   In the question,  I asked about cases besides in *Star Trek Beyond*.

Actually,  these formal uniform hats, as well as the matching admirals' version,  plus those worn by some support of honor guard are prominently shown in *Star Trek Into Darkness* during Pike's funeral:

Answer (score 1):

There is also Worf's promotion scene at the start of *Generations*.

[image]

Comment: Not sure that counts as "Starfleet issued". You think it does?

Comment: No -- it's not just a question about whether anyone ever wore a hat...

Comment: It's a uniform, and a special occasion, for which we have a sample size of of 1. I don't think we can tell. The real WTF of this scene are Troi's high-heel boots.

Comment: i don't see why people are hating this answer